# What is the cutoff parameter stands for in Sphinx SetLimits method?

Tags: sphinx

What is the cutoff parameter stands for in Sphinx SetLimits method?

How can I optimize my queries using it?

I understand that when you use cutoff parameter, Sphinx stops the search when it finds specified count of records.
But is it useful in standard queries with offset/limit ?
Can i win something in efficiency by using it ?

I see only one condition - If I know the exact count of sought-for records.

Answer (score 0):

It can be use used as such, and in some circumstances it can help performance.

In the general case, if you dont care about accuarcy, instead wanting performance, might be worth looking.

But its tricky to use well, need a deep understanding of your results, and specific requirements. Its not a few sentances in a online forum reply.

Comment: hm. It's interesting, what are purposes of this parameter. Docs say it makes Sphinx to return *last* records, but for me it returns first records.

Comment: Docs dont say "which" records will be returned. It depends on a lot of factors, how your index is setup, and the query options used. Thats the point - using it **will be inaccuate**, because you wont work with some of the results (and it's hard to know which ones!). THe purpose is you can sometimes get some performance benefits - but its not a magic bullet.